# mongodb 3.2.6: $lookup and $project rename _id field using mongoid

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections Books and Authors. When I do a lookup between these collections I am getting the desired result but I need to rename "_id" to "id". When I rename those fields, authors "_id" is being replaced with books "_id" instead of authors "_id". Please see below

```
  Book.collection.aggregate([
  {'$lookup' => {'from' => "authors",'
                localField' => "_id",
                'foreignField' => "book_id",
                'as' => "authors"}}
  ])
```

Result:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "title": "abc123",
  "isbn": "0001122223334",
  "copies": 5,
  "updated_at": "2018-03-02T09:17:24.546Z",
  "created_at": "2018-03-02T09:17:24.546Z",
  "authors": [
    {
      "_id": 10,
      "first": "a",
      "last": "a",
      "book_id": 1,
      "updated_at": "2018-03-02T09:22:07.115Z",
      "created_at": "2018-03-02T09:22:07.115Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to rename _id fields to id

```
Book.collection.aggregate([
  {'$lookup' => {'from' => "authors",
                'localField' => "_id",
                'foreignField' => "book_id",
                'as' => "authors"}},
  {'$project' => {'id' => '$_id', '_id' => 0, 'title' => 1, "isbn" => 1, "copies" => 1,  "updated_at" => 1, 
                  "authors" => { 'id' => '$_id', 'first' => 1, 'last' => 1, 'book_id' => 1, 'updated_at' => 1}}}

  ])
```

In the above "project" if I say

```
"authors" => { 'id' => '$_id'
```

Then the result is

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "abc123",
  "isbn": "0001122223334",
  "copies": 5,
  "updated_at": "2018-03-02T09:17:24.546Z",
  "created_at": "2018-03-02T09:17:24.546Z",
  "authors": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first": "a",
      "last": "a",
      "book_id": 1,
      "updated_at": "2018-03-02T09:22:07.115Z",
      "created_at": "2018-03-02T09:22:07.115Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

The id of author is "1", whereas that should be "10".
Please suggest how do I need to make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) authors, project ids, then group back, or use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to reshape authors individually. I believe the later should perform better, but it is a bit less flexible, as you hardcode author's fields:

```
Book.collection.aggregate([
{$addFields: {id:"$_id", "authors": {$map:{
    input: "$authors",
    as: "a",
    in: {
      "id": "$$a._id",
      "first": "$$a.first",
      "last": "$$a.last",
      "book_id": "$$a.book_id",
      "updated_at": "$$a.updated_at",
      "created_at": "$$a.created_at"
    }
}}}},
{$project: {_id:0}}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,just unwind and give this `$authors._id` in project pipe

```
Book.collection.aggregate([
  {'$lookup' => {'from' => "authors",
                'localField' => "_id",
                'foreignField' => "book_id",
                'as' => "authors"}},
  {'$unwind' => '$authors'},
  {'$project' => {'id' => '$authors._id', '_id' => 0, 'title' => 1, "isbn" => 1, "copies" => 1,  "updated_at" => 1, 
                  "authors" => { 'id' => '$_id', 'first' => 1, 'last' => 1, 'book_id' => 1, 'updated_at' => 1}}}
  ])
```

Comment: The book and author ids are swapped, and `$authors._id` is an array. In case there are more than 1 author it will contain ids of all authors.

Comment: so you have to manually add all the fields even though you only want to change _id to id?